# How do I execute Ansible AWX Templates?

Tags: windows, ansible

when trying to launch a playbook from AWX, I receive the error "PLAYBOOK: Missing a revision to run due to failed project update."

My project appears as follows:

[image]

And my template appears as follows:

[image]

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I can't seem to find any answers on the Internet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to add that this playbook is running against Windows servers, running ansible-playbook from a command line using a different playbook which performs windows updates does indeed work.  The credentials listed are "machine" credentials with the username/password as the Windows admin/password.  The Windows servers are not domain joined.

Answer (score 1):

click related Projects and get latest SCM REVISION. refresh to successful

Answer (score 0):

"Missing a revision to run due to failed project update" is due to a failed or missing project update.

I can see on your screenshot that the project update was never done. Do it manually or instruct your project to auto-update on template launch with the option `UPDATE REVISION ON LAUNCH`